# Why does $a^2x^2+(a^2+b^2-c^2)xy+b^2y^2>0,$ imply $(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-4a^2b^2<0$?

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

Why does $a^2x^2+(a^2+b^2-c^2)xy+b^2y^2>0,$ imply $(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-4a^2b^2<0$, if $x, y$ are reals greater than $1$, and $a, b, c$ are positive reals?
A proof with all the math to go from one to the other would be nice.

Comment: Does it mean whe

Comment: Your expression $Q(x, y)$ is a quadratic form. From the general theory of quadratic forms we know that they are positive-definite if the discriminant is positive. Your second expression is the negative of the discriminant.

Comment: Can you explicitly write each part of that proof, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is old incorrect answer ignoring $x>1$ condition. Explanation:

The discriminant is less than $0$ iff for all $x$ the quadratic has no roots.

However, we only know the LHS has no roots for all $x>1$ so this cannot be used. In fact, the counterexample pointed out by @WillJagy shows this.

---

$$a^2x^2+(a^2+b^2-c^2)xy+b^2y^2>0$$

$\implies$ (discriminant for LHS quadratic in $x$ is less than $0$ as the LHS has no roots)

$$(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2y^2-4a^2b^2y^2<0$$

$\implies$

$$(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-4a^2b^2<0$$

Comment: What about the case $x <1$.

Comment: But doesn`t the discriminant being negative would yield complex roots?

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima The problems states $x,y>1$

Comment: @problembuster Discriminant negative iff there are no real roots (as is the case here since the LHS is always greater than $0$).

Comment: @Shuri2060 Thank you very much. I finally got it.

Comment: @problembuster There is a potential problem pointed out by WillJagy meaning the answer does not apply to the question as it is now

Comment: Shuri I added an example to my answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks - the confusion I had was indeed about qualifiers, but I've cleared that up by thinking it over.

$$((\forall x\in A)\,\,\,(P\implies Q)) \implies ((\forall x\in B\subset A)\,\,\,(P\implies Q))$$

but

$$(((\forall x\in B\subset A)\,\,\,P)\implies Q) \implies (((\forall x\in A)\,\,\,P)\implies Q)$$

and of course, $$((\forall x)\,\,\,(P\implies Q)) \not\equiv (((\forall x)\,\,\,P)\implies Q)$$

In addition, $((\forall x\in A)\,\,\,P)\implies Q$ does not necessarily imply $((\forall x\in B\subset A)\,\,\,P)\implies Q$.

Comment: You seem to have interpreted the question as the RHS of $((\forall x)\,\,\,(P\implies Q)) \not\equiv (((\forall x)\,\,\,P)\implies Q)$, but maybe it's still possible to interpret it as the LHS?

Answer (score 6):

since you added a clause about $x,y > 1,$ some two minutes after first posting the question, the conclusion you require is false. In fact, take any $a,b$ (not both zero) at all and then take $c = 0,$ then for $x,y > 1,$
$$  a^2 x^2 + (a^2 + b^2) xy + b^2 y^2 > 0 $$
however
$$  (a^2 + b^2)^2 - 4 a^2 b^2 = (a^2 - b^2)^2 \geq 0 $$

EXAMPLE WITH NONZERO  $c...$  take $a= 20, b = 10, c = 1.$ We find
$$ \color{red}{ 400 x^2 + 499 xy + 100 y^2}  $$
is positive whenever both $x,y$ are bigger than one. HOWEVER, the discriminant is
$$ 499^2 - 4 \cdot 400 \cdot 100 = 499^2 - 400^2 = 99 \cdot 899 = 89001 > 0.  $$
Furthermore, when we take $$ x = 1, y = -2,  $$ we get
$$ 400 - 2 \cdot 499 + 4 \cdot 100 = 400 + 400 - 998 = 800 - 998 = -198. $$
The quadratic form $\langle 400, 499, 100 \rangle$ is positive when both arguments are positive, but not always.

Comment: @Shuri2060 the OP edited in " if x,y are reals greater than 1, " about two minutes after first posting the question. If you click on the phrase "edited 24 minutes ago" you can see the edit history

Comment: I think this means my answer is mistaken?

Comment: @Shuri2060, it does not fit with the final version of the question. At the same time, I do not think the OP has any real idea of what the distinction means. I recommend you keep your answer as it is, just add a new paragraph about the new problem where the inequality is required to hold only when $x,y > 1.$

Comment: My mind's in a bit of a muddle, but doesn't what you've shown just mean that there are no $(x,y)$ which satisfy $a^2 x^2 + (a^2 + b^2) xy + b^2 y^2 > 0$ with the constraints you've given?

Comment: @Shuri2060, it comes down to grammar and the implied quantifiers. Given real $a,b,c.$ If, for all real $x,y,$ not both zero, the expression in the question is positive, then the discriminant is negative. Note that there is already a language problem because of $x=0, y=0.$ Next: given $a,b,c$ real. If, whenever both $x,y > 1,$ the expression is positive, then we know  little about $a,b,c.$ Please try to construct some triples  $a,b,c$ such that the expression given is positive when $x,y > 1,$ but is zero or negative for some specific choices of $x,y,$ e.g. some $x,y$ of opposite $\pm$ signs.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply the inequality by $4a^2$ then add & subtract $(a^2+b^2-c^2)y^2$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underbrace{4a^4 x^2 +4a^2(a^2+b^2-c^2)xy +\color{red}{(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2y^2}}_{} -\color{red}{(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2y^2}+4a^2b^2 y^2>0
\end{eqnarray*}
Now complete the square 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(2a^2x+(a^2+b^2-c^2)y\right)^2+(4a^2b^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2)y^2>0
\end{eqnarray*}
The first term is zero when $2a^2x+(a^2+b^2-c^2)y=0$ . So 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(4a^2b^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2)y^2>0
\end{eqnarray*}
or
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-4a^2b^2<0
\end{eqnarray*}