# Trouble interpreting implicit qualifiers in statement

Tags: logic

Follow up from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364427/why-does-a2x2a2b2-c2xyb2y20-imply-a2b2-c22-4a2b20/2364437?noredirect=1#comment4872697_2364437)

---

> The question asked to show
>
> $$a^2x^2+(a^2+b^2-c^2)xy+b^2y^2>0\implies(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-4a^2b^2<0$$
>
> if $x,y\in\mathbb R_{>1}$ and $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^+$.

---

After submitting my answer, I had a few second thoughts and got a bit confused because of the lack of explicit qualifiers. I thought about it, and realised the important thing here is not to mix up the LHS and RHS of

$$((\forall x)\,\,\,(P\implies Q)) \not\equiv (((\forall x)\,\,\,P)\implies Q)$$

I think the key to my confusion is: **do we interpret the statement with the wording above as the LHS or the RHS, or could it actually be both?**

---

Depending on the answer, then one of these can be used:

$$((\forall x\in A)\,\,\,(P\implies Q)) \implies ((\forall x\in B\subset A)\,\,\,(P\implies Q))\tag{1}$$

$$(((\forall x\in B\subset A)\,\,\,P)\implies Q) \implies (((\forall x\in A)\,\,\,P)\implies Q)\tag{2}$$

I also noted that the inverses of $(1)$ and $(2)$ aren't necessarily true.

---

If I'm not mistaken, I can only use 'quadratic has no roots' iff 'discriminant is negative' for something like $(((\forall x)\,\,\,P)\implies Q)$.

Does this explain why this argument does not help in the linked question as the inverse of $(2)$ isn't necessarily true?

---

I've a feeling I might still have a few things jumbled up - please point them out/correct me if so.

Answer (score 1):

The qualifying statement, "if $x, y \in \Bbb R_{>1}$ and $a,b,c\in \Bbb R^+$", is a universal quantification applying to the entire line.   It was just printed seperately to save space on the line.

$$\forall x{\in}\Bbb R_{>1}\,\forall y{\in}\Bbb R_{>1}\,\forall a{\in}\Bbb R^+\,\forall b{\in}\Bbb R^+\,\forall c{\in}\Bbb R^+~ \Big( P(x,y,a,b,c)\implies Q(x,y,a,b,c)\Big)$$

You can see why.

Comment: Ah I see - In this particular case we get $$\forall x{\in}\Bbb R_{>1}\,\forall y{\in}\Bbb R_{>1}\,\forall a{\in}\Bbb R^+\,\forall b{\in}\Bbb R^+\,\forall c{\in}\Bbb R^+~ \Big( P(x,y,a,b,c)\implies Q(x,y,a,b,c)\Big)$$
$\implies$
$$\forall a{\in}\Bbb R^+\,\forall b{\in}\Bbb R^+\,\forall c{\in}\Bbb R^+~ \Big((\forall x{\in}\Bbb R_{>1}\,\forall y{\in}\Bbb R_{>1} ~P(x,y,a,b,c))\implies Q(a,b,c)\Big)$$
$\implies$
$$\forall a{\in}\Bbb R^+\,\forall b{\in}\Bbb R^+\,\forall c{\in}\Bbb R^+~ \Big((\forall x{\in}\Bbb R\,\forall y{\in}\Bbb R ~P(x,y,a,b,c))\implies Q(a,b,c)\Big)$$But the inverse is false

Comment: The distribution accross implication is in the pattern: $$\forall x~\forall a ~\big(P(x,a)\to Q(a)\big) {\iff \forall a~\forall x~\big(\neg P(x,a)\vee Q(a)\big) \\ \iff \forall a~\Big(\big(\forall x~\neg P(x,a)\big)\vee Q(a)\Big) \\ \iff \forall a~\Big(\big(\exists x~P(x,a)\big)\to Q(a)\Big)}$$